# Notifications for incoming call and call on hold/unhold

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, event-handling, ios7

My application is running in background I want 3 types of notifications in my application:

1. When a phone call comes
2. When the call is on hold
3. When call unholds

Is there any class or framework in iOS which helps me get these in my application?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Well but still the CTCall gives the below states:

1. CTCallStateDialing
2. CTCallStateIncoming
3. CTCallStateConnected
4. CTCallStateDisconnected

What about the hold and unhold states?

Comment: Did you even try to search on net ?

Comment: ofcourse I did. But did not look for the right keywords.

Answer (score 0):

`CTCall` is used to do the calls from the app. Not to detect the normal cellular calls (Only Option is `JailBreaking`).

There is no framework in iOS which will provide you the functionality you are seeking. Its quite logical too. It intrudes User's privacy. Why would I want any app to know my call log? What if it misuses in some other manner?

Hope this explains well.

Comment: Please read the question properly, I do not want any logs. I just want my app to get notified when the call goes on hold and unhold.

Comment: I understand. It was just an abstraction I was pointing at (Call logs will also include the current calls notifications etc.). And your app cannot get notified on general calls. Only calls from the app can be in your control. Is this the case in your app? Otherwise, I can assure you that you can't get notified (in iOS Platform).

Comment: What do you mean by  "calls from the app"

Comment: You can make a call from your apps. If you observe, Phone, which you use to make calls is nothing but an app (:P). Hence it is a call from app (Phone app). Similarly, the call can come from your app, I mean you can tell the iOS framework, that you want to make a call to a number, and it will start a call on behalf of your app. Hope this is clear. Please come on chat, for more discuss on this.